# Inserting data to Windows Azure Table using Android?

Tags: java, c#, android, azure, cloud

I am trying to insert data to a table for which i have created database in sql managment studio and uploaded to window azure.

but I cannot insert data from my android application.

```
/////////main activity/////


private MobileServiceClient MSC;
private MobileServiceTable MST;
User usertable=new User();

Spinner spinner;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_sign_up);

    //for connectivity

    try {
        MSC=new MobileServiceClient(
               "app url",

                "app key",
                this
        );
    } catch (MalformedURLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }


    spinner=(Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    ArrayAdapter adapter=ArrayAdapter.createFromResource(this,R.array.Profession,android.R.layout.simple_dropdown_item_1line);
    spinner.setAdapter(adapter);

    //from here new code for spinner validation

    //till hare code for spinner validation

    Button signUpBotton=(Button)findViewById(R.id.signUpButton);

    signUpBotton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener(){

                                       public void onClick(View view){
                                          // signUpvalidation();
                                         EditText fname= (EditText) findViewById(R.id.etfirstname);
                                           usertable.first_name=fname.getText().toString();

                                           MSC.getTable(User.class).insert(usertable, new TableOperationCallback<User>() {
                                               public void onCompleted(User entity, Exception exception, ServiceFilterResponse response) {
                                                   if (exception == null) {
                                                       // Insert succeeded
                                                   } else {
                                                       // Insert failed
                                                   }

                                               }
                                           });
```

code for class

```
package com.example.engiam.anybodyhere;
import com.microsoft.azure.storage.OperationContext;


/**
 * Created by imdad on 8/28/2015.
 */
public class User {

    public String id;
    public String first_name;

}
```

Comment: You are not using the exception infos to check for error in your code if the insert failed, maybe you should start there.

Comment: don't understand please if you can explain it!!

Comment: In the test  `if (exception == null) { ...` nothing is done with the exception if the insertion failed, perhaps use `printStackTrace` then read the android error log could help find the error

Answer (score 0):

Per my experience, the cause of insert date failed form your android app is that the POJO class "User" is incorrect.

I refer to the POJO class "ToDoItem" from Azure Mobile Service sample https://github.com/Azure/mobile-services-samples/blob/master/GettingStarted/Android/ZUMOAPPNAME/src/com/example/zumoappname/ToDoItem.java to rewrite the User POJO Class as the below:

```
package com.example.engiam.anybodyhere;

public class User {

    @com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName("id")
    private String id;

    @com.google.gson.annotations.SerializedName("first_name")
    private String firstName;

    public User() {}

    public User(String id, String firstName) {
         this.setId(id);
         this.setFirstName(firstName);
    }

    public String getId() {
         return id;
    }

    public String setId(String id) {
         this.id = id;
    }

    public String getFirstName() {
         return firstName;
    }

    public String setId(String firstName) {
         this.firstName = firstName;
    }

     // If you need to override function toString & equals, please follow the sample to write them. 

 }
```

The Java annotations in the POJO class above are related with the table columns in the database if the class property names are different form the table column names. If the code not annotate table column name, the program don't know how to insert the data item into the correct table column.

And your class code is missing the setting & getting method, it will cause the dynamic schema will not inject the User object and get its properties to insert them into the table or create a new table. About the Dynamic Schema, please refer to https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/azure/jj193175.aspx.

You need to modify your main activity code by using set & get function as following the POJO class specification.

Any concerns, please comment me.
Best Regards.